# TCP CLOSE_WAIT apple apns

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, asp.net-core-1.1

We are currently on asp.NET Core 1.1.4
The `ApnsStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync()` never returns. We tried using netstat and the connection shows up as CLOSE_WAIT. We also verified that the certificate works by sending a manual push notification through the pusher desktop app.

We changed the SSL protocol to `tls and tls1` to see if it would error out, but no luck.

`

```
private async Task<bool> OpenSslStreamAsync(string host, X509CertificateCollection certificates)
        {
            Logger.Info("Creating SSL connection.");
            ApnsStream = new SslStream(ApnsClient.GetStream(), false, ValidateServerCertificate, SelectLocalCertificate);

            try
            {
                await ApnsStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(host, certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, false).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            if (!ApnsStream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated)
            {
                Logger.Error("SSL Stream Failed to Authenticate");
                return false;
            }

            if (!ApnsStream.CanWrite)
            {
                Logger.Error("SSL Stream is not Writable");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

`

EDIT:

I tried it on Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code this time and did receive an exception:

> one or more errors occurred Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: connection reset by peer

Visual Studio had framework target of 1.0.4. Once I changed that back to 1.1 like visual studio code it also just hangs.

Is the `AuthenticateAsClientAsync` api broken in core 1.1?